# Jenkins searchbox result URLs incorrect

Tags: jenkins

We have a problem with the URLs returned by the Jenkins search functionality.

Our Jenkins URL is, say, https://example.com/jenkins

Jenkins sits behind a reverse proxy (HAProxy).  We've configured HAProxy as follows:

```
frontend buildserver
        bind *:443 ssl crt /etc/ssl/certs/example.com.pem
        http-request set-header X-Forwarded-Proto https
        http-request set-header X-Forwarded-Host example.com
        http-request set-header X-Forwarded-Port 443
        acl PATH_JENKINS path_beg -i /jenkins
        use_backend jenkins-http if PATH_JENKINS

backend jenkins-http
        server jenkins 127.0.0.1:8080
```

and in /etc/default/jenkins we have:

```
JENKINS_ARGS="--webroot=/var/cache/$NAME/war --httpPort=$HTTP_PORT --prefix=/jenkins"
```

In the GUI configuration we have Jenkins URL set to:

```
https://example.com/jenkins/
```

Everything appears to work and I can navigate all links in Jenkins with the exception of any search results generated using the search box on the top panel.  These search results link to the job/view/etc URL without the "/jenkins/" prefix and therefore don't work.

We have recently upgraded Jenkins and I'm told the search results previously worked.

Has anybody else seen this issue?

Ubuntu, Jenkins 2.289.2

UPDATE:  I downgraded to our previous version 2.263.4 but the problem still persists.  Inspecting the HTML shows the generated hrefs are relative and unusual, eg:

```
<a href="../../../../../../../../../../../../../../job/myjob">myjob</a>
```

I can get it working by editing like this:

```
<a href="../job/myjob">myjob</a>
```

I've also noticed the below search text help appear after a search.  I don't see that on other instances of Jenkins I have access to.  Is this enabled by configuration / plugin perhaps?

[image]

**POSSIBLE SOLUTION**: so the image above is the nested-view plugin.  Issues have been reported with this, eg:

https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-65924

I rolled back the plugin from 1.20 to 1.17 and now have the more familiar search functionality back and working.  phew.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like the issue is solved with 1.26 and I haven't had to create a `~/.nestedViewsSearch` file.

https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T294424#8028735

Answer (score 2):

Had the same issue. Downgraded nested-view to 1.19 from 1.21 and search issue went away.

Answer (score 2):

[nested-view v1.24](https://plugins.jenkins.io/nested-view/#releases) ([diff](https://github.com/jenkinsci/nested-view-plugin/compare/nested-view-1.23...nested-view-1.24#diff-64bc3e4913085d9a6d1ef172cad8895dd883e3315fee0969b6a11522a63bbed3)) allows restoring default search behavior by creating a file named `~/.nestedViewsSearch` on the Jenkins controller.

This takes effect immediately; it is not necessary to restart the controller.

Answer (score 1):

Nested view continue to provide its own  search extension, because other searches are unable to crawl nested views correctly.
The life-saving hack of `~/.nestedViewsSearch` was removed in nested-view-1.27, which was released today. Instead of it, the nested view search cabe disabeld temoprarily by `-X:` or `-Xn:` (see help) switch, or permanently via  **global settings** of jenkins.`~/.nestedViewsSearch` remiasn correct for older versions, but are no longer valid.

Answer (score 1):

We're at version 1.32 and it is still a problem. In case you aren't ready to upgrade or the upgrade doesn't work for you, just run the script below (buried in Antoine's link) from the Script Runner:

```
new File(System.getProperty("user.home"),'.nestedViewsSearch').createNewFile()
```

Beware that it'll be lost when you restart the instance and you'll have to do it again.
[image: script console method]

If you are still having problems, you can just turn off the nested view search extension... the ugly page will go away, and you'll still be able to search for job... just not within nested views (which IMO is on overkill/unnecessary 'feature' anyway).

[image: global settings method]

If you are using configuration as code option, you'll want to set 'nestedViewSearch: false'.

[image: configuration as code method]